# Creating an nested record in Avro schema for a simple json

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, avro

I'm trying to build an Avro schema for the following json (for Hadoop):

```
{
  "name_tag":"Guy",
  "known_nested_structure" : {
    "fieldA" : ["value1"],
    "fieldB" : ["value1","value2"],
    "fieldC" : [],
    "fieldD" : ["value1"]
  },
  "another_field" : "hi"
}
```

My first idea was this avro schema (including the hive commands):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS record_table
     PARTITIONED BY (YEAR INT, MONTH INT, DAY INT, HOUR INT)
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
     STORED AS
     INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
     OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
     LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost/data/output/records_data/hourly'
     TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='{
  "name": "myRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name":"name_tag", "type":"string",c"default": ""},
    {
      "name": "known_nested_structure",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
          {"name":"fieldA", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
          {"name":"fieldB", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
          {"name":"fieldC", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
          {"name":"fieldD", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null}
        ],
        "default":null
    },
    {"name": "another_field","type":"string","default": ""}
  ]
}');
```

The hive result of the command:
    OK
    error_error_error_error_error_error_error   string  from deserializer
    cannot_determine_schema string  from deserializer
    check   string  from deserializer
    schema  string  from deserializer
    url string  from deserializer
    and string  from deserializer
    literal string  from deserializer
    year    int 
    month   int 
    day int 
    hour    int 
    Time taken: 0.128 seconds

But for some reason this is the avro schema that works.

```
{
  "name": "myRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name":"name_tag", "type":"string","default": null},
    {
  "name": "known_nested_structure",
  "type": {
        "name": "known_nested_structure",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
                {"name":"fieldA", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
                {"name":"fieldB", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
                {"name":"fieldC", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null},
                {"name":"fieldD", "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"},"default":null}
              ],
              "default":null

       }
    },
        {"name": "another_field","type": "string","default": null}
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
OK
name_tag    string  from deserializer
known_nested_structure          struct<fielda:array<string>,fieldb:array<string>,fieldc:array<string>,fieldd:array<string>>         from deserializer
another_field   string  from deserializer
year    int 
month   int 
day int 
hour    int 
Time taken: 0.123 seconds
```

What is the reason that the first avro schema doesn't work? Why can't I put a record directly as a field (known_nested_structure is in known_nested_structure in my second schema example)?

Thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see the AvroSerde uses the Avro api and to parse the Schema, it uses the org.apache.avro.Schema 's parse() method. If you look into the method you could clearly see that it does a recursive call to parse when reading the fields. So, if you have a "record" in your fields, it would need to follow the same convention as the (name, type="record", fields[]) sequence. That is the possible reason why your second avro worked and the first one failed.  grepcode on org.apache.avro.Schema and it should explain.

Answer (score 1):

There is one error I can see in your schema(**c** before default):

```
{"name":"name_tag", "type":"string",c"default": ""},
```

It should be:

```
{"name":"name_tag", "type":"string","default": ""},
```

Comment: Thanks, it was probably in the copy & paste. It's not in the code :)